# inotifywait adding multiple files at ones

Tags: bash, shell, inotifywait

this shell script should add everything put in the folder to transmission. With one folder it works fine, but when i add more then one folder at the same moment it ignores the second one.

```
while true; 
do
file=$(inotifywait -e moved_to --format %f /srv/watchfolderfilme)
file="/srv/watchfolderfilme/$file" 
   transmission-create -o $file.torrent -s 16384 -t http://0.0.0.0:6969/announce $file
   mv $file /srv/downloads
   chmod 0777 $file.torrent
   cp $file.torrent /srv/newtorrentfiles
   mv $file.torrent /srv/watchfoldertorrents  
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rethough my solution and found a better one that works fine for multiple adds

```
inotifywait -m /srv/watchfolderfilme -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
#  echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
   chmod 0777 $path$file
   transmission-create -o /srv/newtorrentfiles/$file.torrent -s 16384 -t http://0.0.0.0:6969/announce $path$file
   mv $path$file /srv/downloads
   chmod 0777 /srv/newtorrentfiles/$file.torrent
   cp /srv/newtorrentfiles/$file.torrent /srv/watchfoldertorrents
done
```